# Inputing Data into Shiny- for a bar graph

Tags: r, input, shiny

I am trying to insert a bar graph from a dataset that I have into Shiny to make a simple bar graph of the data. This is my code thus far:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

excel_data <- read_excel(path = system.file("CHAMPdata_gender/datasets.xlxs", package = "readxl"))

ui <- fluidPage(
   mainPanel(
plotlyOutput("chart")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$chart <- renderPlotly({
# write code here to read data from csv file


# Set x and y axis and display data in bar chart using plotly
p <- plot_ly( x = CHAMPdata_gender$X,
              y = CHAMPdata_gender$Total.Respond, CHAMPdata_gender$Never,   CHAMPdata_gender$Less.than.one.year, CHAMPdata_gender$One.year.or.more,
              name = "Childhood data",
              type = "bar") 
    })
 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am currently trying to learn Shiny in R, so would appreciate all the help I can get! thanks

Comment: Hello Cameron, welcome to SO. What exactly is the question?

Comment: Hi, I am working on creating a bar graph for the data that I have that is entitled "CHAMPdata_gender"; ideally I would like it to be interactive; that is the code that I worked on, but it is not working....what are the errors? do you have any resources that could help me in creating just a simple interactive bar chart.

Comment: Could you add a  sample of your data so that this is reproducable on other peoples' systems? Without giving us anything reproducable we can only stare at your code hoping to find something. And we do not have access to your Excel file. What is the content of `CHAMPdata_gender`? And - by the way - where is it defined? Your sample does not show how you turn `excel_data` into `CHAMPdata_gender`.